Azure routing between different subscriptions - force one, common outbound IP and share Site-to-site (IPSec) defined in Virtual network gateway
So I have 3 Azure subscriptions: Staging, Dev1 and Dev2.
In the Staging I have:

Virtual network with:


defaultSubnet 10.0.0.0/24
GatewaySubnet 10.0.1.0/24


Virtual network gateway with connection Site-to-site (IPsec) (BGP disabled) connected to GatewaySubnet
NAT gateway with static outbound IP connected to defaultSubnet
WebApp integrated with Virtual network/defaultSubnet

And everything is working fine:

WebApp can connect to resources via priver IPs over Site-to-site (IPsec)
If accessing public IPs over Iternet WebApp traffic is directed over static outbound IP

It's necessary as 3rd party services which WebApp is using are either whitelisting IPs (so static outbound) or require IPsec connection.
The problem is, that I want to use the same outbound IP and IPsec connection for WebApp1 and WebApp2 located in Dev1 and Dev2 subscriptions respectively.
The connections to the 3rd party services includes REST, SOAP, FTP(s) so ideally I'd like to have it resolved on the transport layer.
I've tried many different things:

Created virtual network (with gateway and without) in Dev1
Assigned WebApp1 to the virtual network
Created peering from the vnet to the vnet from Staging
Created connectivity configuration in Network Manager
Created routes

Unfortunately the only result I've got is the ability to ping WebApp (Staging) from WebApp1 (Dev1) and vice versa. But I cannot access 3rd party resources over IPsec from WebApp1 and also I cannot force WebApp1 to use static outbound IP from Staging subscription.
I've followed a couple responses from SO (including this which was quite promising) but apparently I'm doing something wrong. Can you please direct me to the right solution, as Azure provides so many settings in aforementioned components, that I probably configured something wrong...
I'm also willing to use some 3rd party solutions available in the Azure, if necessary.
EDIT:
Following the solution from the response I encountered a problem to provide settings as described. When creating a peering from dev to staging and trying to setup: Enable 'dev1-virtual-net' to use 'staging-test's' remote gateway or route server I'm getting "
'dev1-virtual-net' cannot use 'staging-test's' remote gateway or route server because it already has a gateway or route server in the virtual network." as I have Route Server, on the other hand if I remove Route Server I cannot select "Allow gateway or route server in 'dev1-virtual-net' to forward traffic to the peered virtual network". If I understood your description, both should be checked which seems impossible...


Create a centralized Virtual Network (VNet) in the Staging subscription, which will act as the "hub" VNet. In this hub VNet, you will have the Virtual Network Gateway (for IPsec VPN) and NAT Gateway (for a static outbound IP).

You can use a hub-and-spoke architecture with Virtual Network Peering and Forced Tunneling. This setup will allow resources in the Dev1 and Dev2 subscriptions to route outbound traffic through the Staging subscription’s Virtual Network Gateway and NAT Gateway.

OK, after further digging I've created hub-spoke setup, but I'm still missing something, e.g I created custom route for ifconfig.me (destination IP: 34.160.111.0/24, next hop virtual network gateway) and I cannot reach ifconfig.me from dev1 environment, once I remove the route, ifconfig.me is working OK, bu (of course) my external IP is from dev1 NAT gateway not from the staging NAT gateway :-(


I want to use the same outbound IP and IPsec connection for WebApp1 and WebApp2 located in Dev1 and Dev2 subscriptions respectively.

Since native Azure networking doesn't fully support above requirements
Firstly, Fix virtual network Peering and Gateway Settings

In the Staging Virtual Network Peering, Check Allow gateway transit is enabled.
In the Dev1 and Dev2 VNets, check Use remote gateway is enabled, Allow forwarded traffic is enabled.

Set up User-Defined Routes (UDRs) in Dev1 and Dev2 to direct traffic appropriately
For Internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0):

Next hop: Virtual Network Gateway (Staging VNet).

For On-premises IPs via IPsec:

Next hop: Virtual Network Gateway (Staging VNet).

Azure Firewall supports SNAT (Source NAT) for peered networks. Deploying it in the Staging subscription allows to centralize outbound traffic and enforce the use of a single static IP.

Deploy Azure Firewall in the Staging VNet.

Configure DNAT/SNAT rules for internet-bound traffic. Default route in the Staging VNet to direct 0.0.0.0/0 to Azure Firewall.

Update UDRs in Dev1 and Dev2 to route all internet-bound traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to the Staging Azure Firewall.


By this setup you can be able to share the outbound static IP and IPsec connection configured in the Staging subscription to WebApps in Dev1 and Dev2.

I'll check this out ASAP, thanks!

They've put me temporarily into another project, I'll try it as soon as I'll get back to it, thanks for the answer.

I tried you approach, but I have problem with peering settings, more info in EDIT of the original post.
